# PHP - preg_replace - use other substitution if the current one is empty

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('/\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/', '<a href="\1">\2</a>', $input);
```

For this data

```
$input = "[link=xxx]xxx[/link] [link=yyy][/link]"
```

it produces:

```
<a href="xxx">xxx</a> <a href="yyy"></a>
```

However, I would like the result to be

```
<a href="xxx">xxx</a> <a href="yyy">yyy</a>
```

Can I somehow use `\2` and if the string is empty, use `\1` instead in `preg_replace` replacement? I dont want to use callback version of `preg_replace`.

Comment: Not to belabour the same thing over and over again, but you should avoid parsing HTML using regex.

Comment: You'll have to use `preg_replace_callback`. The replacement does not support expressions, and the regex can't set a single capture group to either or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mario pointed out, you need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for a problem like this. Inside the callback you can check if there is a second group match, and if not, repeat the first match inside the `<a>` element:

```
$input = "[link=xxx]xxx[/link] [link=yyy][/link]";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/', 
                           function ($m) { 
                               return "<a href=\"$m[1]\">" . (strlen($m[2]) ? $m[2] : $m[1]) . '</a>'; 
                           },
                           $input);
```

Output

```
<a href="xxx">xxx</a> <a href="yyy">yyy</a>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/R2CRU)